# Ebean-model get customer info and identities without taking debts by @onetomany relation

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am new on Play framework and trying to make a project. Maybe some parts I would went wrong, if so please correct me. I have 3 models which are customers,identities, and debts. A customer has one identity and has many debts. While I am trying to get only customer and its identities, coming results include its debts. Where is my mistake? In my models or I am searching wrong way?

Customers.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customers extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int id;

public int identity_id;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd/MM/yy")
public Date register_date;

public boolean status;
public Date closing_date;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date created_at;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date updated_at;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="identity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
public Identities identity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Debts> debts;

public static final Finder<Long, Customers> find = new Finder<>(
        Long.class, Customers.class);

}
```

Identities.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="identities")
public class Identities extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int id;

@Constraints.Required
public int customer_id;

public Long citizen_no;
public String full_name;

@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date birthdate;

public Integer place_of_birth;
public String father_name;
public String mother_name;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date created_at;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date updated_at;

public static final Model.Finder<Long, Identities> find = new Model.Finder<>(
        Long.class, Identities.class);
}
```

Debts.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="debts")
public class Debts extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;

public int customer_id;
public Integer payment_id;

@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date billed_date;

public Float cost;
public Float taxes;
public boolean status;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date created_at;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public Date updated_at;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Customers customer;


public static final Model.Finder<Long, Debts> find = new Model.Finder<>(
        Long.class, Debts.class);
}
```

CustomerController.java

```
public class CustomersController extends BaseController {

public Result show(long id) {

    Customers customer = Customers.find.select("*")
            .fetch("identity")
            .where()
            .eq("id", id)
            .findUnique();

    return ok(Json.toJson(customer));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it include the `Debts` only populated with the debt.id? Or is it querying the full Debt object?

Comment: It is querying the full Debt object thats what I dont want to see.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work or even if it is the correct solution, but you can try adding: `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: Is it a lot of work to create a sample project and place it on github? I cannot help you with reproducing it myself, if I can help of course :-)

Comment: Also: can you remove `.select("*")` and keep the lazy fetch and try again

Comment: For the same query after deleting .select("*") the result was same, but when I make .fetch("debts")  incoming json result's identity field returned null. Before that query, identity field had json object. I didn't get the logic.